# Typescript: force to call super when override some method

Tags: typescript

I have a base class `BaseComponent` with a method `foo()` and I want all the classes that extends my `BaseComponent` and override the method `foo()`, always call the super method:

```
export class BaseComponent {
    foo(){}
}

export class ExtendedComponent extends BaseComponent  {

    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    // BAD
    foo(){
    }

    // GOOD
    foo(){
       super.foo();
    }
}
```

Some trick in Typescript?

Comment: You can try the Receipt approach suggested by the great jcalz: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21388#issuecomment-360214959. As far as I know, there is no good solution to that problem.

Comment: You can "force" it by design: Base class should have the method that you want consumers to call. It should not be overridden. Instead there should be a protected abstract method containing only the part of the logic you want to override. The public baseclass method simply looks like this: `foo() { abstractFoo(); /* mySuperFooStuff */ }` ... It's that simple. If your foo method contains logic that always needs to run, then don't override it - split it up into overridable and non-overridable parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no official way yet (in TS 4.5) to do so. I however [opened this ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21388#issuecomment-934345226) with the [following workaround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDCB7AtgBxQOwdgLtAN4CwAUNNBgE4CWAbmPgtBPk7cNMGCCAMoBXDAmoAxFCmgBeaPwCeaAEYoQACgDkSXiFrYA5tABmO6LRhow2ACZMU1eRoCUAbnLlKRyWqfEPlaGoEfEFqbDhEVEwcPHwAOh4+IRFxSTcKaABfcmyyclBIGABRAA9mGwRrKKxcAmgEMrxrGHgIZHQa2L8MrxQfboDoAHoh6AB1Wj5jMEnofClgDsmWAHdafAALFEFCTfNoXVx-SiCQsNZhUTjen3TKXNygA):

```
class BaseComponent {
  private static callSuperFoo = Symbol('Calling super.foo is mandatory');

  foo() {
    return BaseComponent.callSuperFoo;
  }
}

class ExtendedComponent extends BaseComponent {
  foo() {
    // Will fail to compile without this line
    return super.foo();
  }
}
```

Explanation:
The super class is having a private static symbol `callSuperFoo`. Meaning

- The `Symbol` is always unique, i.e. by design you cannot create another `Symbol` with the same signature.
- It is `static` and therefore bound to the class
- It is `private`, meaning, there is no way for sub classes to directly access this symbol.
- The super method foo returns the the symbol meaning it's return type is inferred to `typeof<BaseComponent.callSuperFoo>`
- The sub method foo (overriding method) must have the same signature as it's parent, it must therefore return the private super class symbol. But the only way to access and return this symbol is going threw the `super.foo()` method. Remember, `callSuperFoo`is private,  meaning you cannot even force casting a variable to `typeof<BaseComponent.callSuperFoo>`.

With this workaround, there is no way to override foo properly without calling the super.foo method.

To summarize: the sub method must return the same unique value as it's parent one, and as only it's parent is returning it: the sub method must call it's parent.

Note: This works when `foo` is not returning anything i.e. is `void`, it would be more complicated if this was not the case (I did not dug this case btw).

[EDIT]
As @Olivier Clément found a flaw, here is an [even stricter typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDCB7AtgBxQOwdgLtAN4CwAUNNBgE4CWAbmPgtBPk7cNMGCCAMoBXDAmoAxFCmgBeaPwCeaAEYoQACgDkSXiFrYA5q2GiAdADNJ0WjDRhsAEyYpq8jQEoA3OXKULKNW7EPpTQ1Aj4gtTY0IIOCGZ6CPbQkND48iIoZnCIqJg4ePgmPHxCIuKWAGTQuPSiXhTQAL7kLWTkoJAwAKIAHsxx9nlYuATQCP149jDwEMjoI4VBjX4ByyHQAPSb0ADqtHzQZmAHaVLACwcsAO60+AAWKIKED9bQurjBlGERUUbl5kkAQalDabQ64Cg0D6A3sSWGBQIACZxpMHDNcgtEYRSI1tmkMnpDKk7PJoPYUAgYNgUIRrs4ANbBVZuABcKWwZNxGx+kWwwTB3jInShMKm8Kxo3wAGZUbCMXMEVL1lsdjTCDoUNckjUEHd7qJmUC2dAAErhPkAFQyCAAPLN5vkpYD-G4AHwq74WqIC1pCoA)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to do the trick either;
You can simply set the return type of `foo(): any` and it will compile just fine.

Alternatively, even typing baseFoo(): typeof BaseComponent.callSuperFoo and returning any other symbol will compile

See here: [See here](shorturl.at/htwHJ)

Comment: I updated the answer, please let me know if you still find other flaws on this workaround (other than still being an ugly hack)

Comment: I think there's no way to force a super call. This example shows another flaw: shorturl.at/ekGP4

Comment: The url is not working anymore. BTW, you are right, there is no clean way yet… we can always overload using "any". This is however better than nothing.

Comment: IMO this answer author solution does the job well. The intention is to let user know that he/she needs to call a super method if overriding the class. Oliver's method does not work so well, as it returns Promise<never>, and that is not unique per super class. I can call override methodB() {return super.methodA()} and it will still work. Flavien's solution will not let it do that. you can bring callSuperFoo to module's global scope aand export type FooOverride = typeof callSuperFoo; so consumer classes can override safely.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround:

```
export class BaseComponent {
  constructor() {
    const original = this.foo;
    this.foo = () => {
      BaseComponent.prototype.foo.apply(this);
      return original.apply(this);
    };
  }

  foo() {
    console.log("BaseComponent.foo");
  }
}

export class ExtendedComponent extends BaseComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  foo() {
    console.log("ExtendedComponent.foo");
  }
}

const extendedComponent = new ExtendedComponent();
extendedComponent.foo();
```

Output:

```bash
BaseComponent.foo
ExtendedComponent.foo
```

This way the parent method will be called anytime the child method is called without forcing the user to call `super.foo()`.

**Note**: This will not continue the chain for subclasses, the only methods that will be called is the first and the last one in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you ["virtual" and "override" keywords](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1524)

In TypeScript 4.2 should be available. Check the [iteration plan](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41601)